# Powershell or batch file help required with script for setting up a scheduled task

Tags: powershell

So we are all aware of this screen below

[Windows Nag Screen - Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlH1P.png)

I have multiple computers on a newwork that require to be rebooted in the middle of the night, they are supposed to be playing a video on them every reboot and it loops on a system.

this pop up nag screen keeps appearing on random systems and I need to remote into them and disable by pressing SKIP for now.

I have some questions

1. when you press Skip for now - will this screen pop up AGAIN at some stage?
2. can I run a batch file to kill this process and will it then come up again once I reboot the system?
3. can Powershell be run and remotely press the "skip for now" button on any machines if this screen exists on any of them? so I can set it up as a scheduled task or something after each reboot?

Comment: Looks like a GPO or config job from a quick [Google search](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-get-even-more-out-of-windows-in-windows-10/).

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this, but maybe
[How to disable "Get even more out of Windows" on Windows 10](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/08/09/how-to-disable-get-even-more-out-of-windows-on-windows-10)
helps?
If not, you could try using "SendKeys": Supposed you could press Alt + "s" for "Skip for now" use this:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%s")
```

Comment: This looks interesting Marc, are you suggesting that this is something run in a schedule task at startup delayed that can click skip for me?

Comment: I suppose so, you should give it a try. At least it works when running a powershell script interactively (not in the background).